# A woman invites a nonempty subset of twelve friends to a party. Two friends are recently divorced and cannot both be invited at the same time.

Tags: combinatorics

I found a solution online that gives:

$$2^{12} - 1 - 2^{10}$$

Why would we not have

$$2^{12} - 1 - 2^{10} - 1$$

instead? Since we want a non-empty subset. If we use the first solution, wouldn't that mean we are also getting rid of the case where no friends are chosen?

Answer (score 1):

Set $\{1,2,3,\dots,12\}$ has $2^{12}$ subsets.

Exactly $2^{10}$ of these subsets contain $1$ and $2$ as elements, so there are $2^{12}-2^{10}$ subsets that do not contain both elements.

One of these $2^{12}-2^{10}$ subsets is the empty set, and discarding it we find $$2^{12}-2^{10}-1$$ subsets that do not contain $1$ as well as $2$ and are not empty.